# Split a list of elements into sub lists, each with different criteria

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I have a list of elements of different values, say 0 to 3. I want to split it into a certain number of sub lists, each accepting only certains elements. The sub lists may not always have the same length.

For example, I have a list of 12 elements: `[0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`. I want to split it into 3 sub lists:

- One that accepts all elements.
- One that only accepts 1, 2 and 3. That list could be `[1,1,2,2]` but not `[0,0,2,3]`.
- One that only accepts 0, 2 and 3. That list could be `[0,0,2,3]` but not `[1,1,2,2]`.

A sub list that accepts elements doesn't mean it needs to contain these elements.

I tried filling each sub list in order with random elements from the parent list meeting the sub list criteria. With the example above, it could go like this:

- Fill the 1st list: `[0,0,0,2]`. Parent list is now `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]`.
- Fill the 2nd list: `[2,2,3,3]`. Parent list is now `[1,1,1,3]`.
- Try to fill the 3rd list: only `[1,1,1,3]` is left but this list can't take 1s. Start again.

Because of the use of random this could never end in the worst case.

The algorithm must give uniform results, all combinations of sub lists having the same probability to be chosen.

**Context:** This is for a card game where the computer plays using Information Set Monte Carlo Tree Search. One step is too make a randomized state of the game from the point of view of a player. All cards unknown to the observer are shuffled together (making the parent list) and redistributed (the sub lists). In this particular game, the player has a way to know that other players may not have cards of a particular suit, so in the randomized state step, no cards of these suits should be distributed to those players (hence why sub lists can have certain values).

In this context there will always be 2 or 3 sub lists, and each sub list will always have between 1 and 13 elements. The difference in the size of two sub lists is never greater than 1.

Comment: **Please add a reference to the original problem _in the question_**. Why is this important? Reasons. 1) Credit should be attributed. 2) The original problem is probably stated clearer. 3) A reference will motivate people easily. 4) A reference may save readers who look for related materials lots of time. 5) I will skip this reason for the moment.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I added some context, hope it helps.

Comment: Here is my salute to the original source and the original researcher.

Comment: Can we assume the number of sublists is very small? For example, less than 10?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention there is always 2 or 3 sublists.

Comment: Are the lengths of the sublists specified as part of the problem, or are you allowed to make them all any size you want?  Either way, you can solve the problem of finding *a* solution in polynomial time, as it's the Assignment Problem (finding a maximum matching in a bipartite graph) in disguise.  Not sure how to choose uniformly randomly from the set of all such solutions though.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Thanks, I'll look it up. The lengths range from 1 to 13 and two sub lists cannot have a difference in length greater than 1.

Comment: OK, please edit your question to include that constraint.  The Assignment Problem can be solved efficiently whenever each sublist ("worker") has a fixed minimum and maximum number of elements ("tasks") that can/must be assigned to it, and fortunately the constraint you gave can be expressed this way :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Can you expand a little on how to apply the Assignement Problem to my case, or give some useful references? I'm having a hard time figuring it out from the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Suppose there are $n$ elements, and $k$ sublists ($k$ is 2 or 3).  We will make a bipartite graph consisting of 2 sets of vertices, "tasks" ($A$) and "workers" ($B$).  Make a "task" vertex in set $A$ for each element (so $n$ of these).  For each sublist, make $\lceil n/k \rceil$ "worker" vertices in set $B$, and add an edge between each of these "worker" vertices and every "task" vertex in set $A$ that corresponds to an element that *could be* assigned to this sublist.  Finally run the Hungarian algorithm, or other algorithm for solving the Assignment Problem, on this graph.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Ok thanks. Why make $\lceil n/k \rceil$ workers and not just the same number as the sublist final size (sublists may not all have the same size)? Also I've looked up the Hungarian algorithm and it seems there might be a simpler/faster algorithm since there are no weights and matches are limited to two vertices? Or is there random weights?

Comment: I interpreted your statement "The lengths range from 1 to 13 and two sub lists cannot have a difference in length greater than 1" to mean that you *don't* know exactly how long each sublist must be, rather you know only that you can't have two sublists that differ in length by more than 1.  That scenario is modelled by making $\lceil n/k \rceil$ workers for each sublist: For each sublist, the final assignment will either assign all $\lceil n/k \rceil$ of them to elements, or leave exactly one unassigned.

Comment: If you know the specific sizes of each sublist (I tried to ask this in my original question), then of course just use those.

Comment: Regarding the algorithm, the Ford-Fulkerson maximum flow algorithm is probably the easiest to implement yourself, though it's still a bit of work.  More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs.  But probably the easiest practical way is just to use an existing LP solver, e.g. lp_solve or SCIP: finding a maximum cardinality matching in a bipartite graph (the problem you have) is a special case of linear programming, and any implementation of the simplex algorithm will quickly find an optimal integral solution on moderate-size instances.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I just got around to implement this solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome :)